# How to solve differential equations (ODE) using Monte Carlo methods?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, monte-carlo

The type of differential equations I am particularly interested in is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ with initial condition $y(0)=a$. I looked up almost everywhere online to find the details on how to solve it using Monte Carlo but only could find one research paper. Link to which is given below. They did solve the equation of the same type as given above but what they did was not at all clear. It would be really helpful if somebody could explain to me how.

http://static.bsu.az/w24/PIAMV4%20N2%202015/6%20Akhtar.pdf

Comment: An ODE IVP is given by the integral equation $y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(z,y(z)) dz$. This latter integral can be computed using Monte Carlo integration provided that either $f$ doesn't actually depend on $y$ or some guess for $y(x)$ at the randomly chosen points is available for refinement. Even upon a brief look at this paper, it is not apparent to me how the authors of this paper get around the latter issue in cases where $f$ depends on $y$. Indeed their pseudocode has such terse notation that I cannot make heads or tails of Algorithm 2.

Comment: Have you looked up Gillespie's method?

Comment: Gillespie's method seems considerably less general than this to me (specific to mass action type equations like SIR models).

Comment: I still don't understand how to proceed with the equation you provided. $y(z)$ is still unknown, right? Can you provide a procedure?

Comment: It looks like Algorithm 2 says: generate a random partition of $[-R,M]$, compute the current $f(x,y)$, then increment $x$ by $\Delta x$ and increment $y$ by $\operatorname{sign}(f(x,y)) \Delta x/N$ times the number of random numbers in the partition between $0$ and $f(x,y)$. It's not apparent to me what advantage this has over forward Euler.

Comment: Is there a general procedure for solving above given differential equation using Monte Carlo?